# Adding unique items to list. Do I need to be concerned of performance?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to check whether new items have appeared in the list `B` in each iteration of a simulation and if so append the new value(s) to `A`. From my research, I have come to the conclusion that this is the most common way to solve this (not using sets, I want to keep the list ordered):

```
A = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']
B = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd','ee'] # Read only

[A.append(b) for b in B if not b in A]
```

However, this approach seems quite computationally heavy and I wonder if this concern is justified? And if so, is there another approach with better performance?

I know that `B` will not be updated that often (probably in much less than 1% of the iterations), and that `A` might hold more values that are not present in `B` but should be kept.

Comment: I do not know exactly how these libraries are implemented, but there are several like this one (https://pypi.org/project/ordered-set/). Maybe you can look into it.

Comment: What ordering should the list have? lexicographic? insertion order?

Comment: @L.Grozinger It should be kept in insertion order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could only do it for new items added to B, rather than all, by intercepting the  append/insert/extend calls.  Then just apply your logic to only incoming elements.

Should more or less fit with your requirements as B doesn't get frequent updates but is apparently liable to grow quite large.  If you wanted to get really fancy, you could even manage a `set` to hold already-in-A values, but that's trading memory for speed and I'd wait to see actual profiling to see if the complexity was worthwhile.

```
A = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']
B = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd','ee'] # Read only

[A.append(b) for b in B if not b in A]

class myB:

    def __init__(self, A, B):
        self.li = B
        self.A = A

    def insert(self, i, x):
        self.li.insert(i, x)
        if not x in self.A:
            self.A.append(x)

    def append(self, x):
        self.li.append(x)

        if not x in self.A:
            self.A.append(x)

    #override extend...


#set up intercept
B2 = myB(A, B)

print(f"ante:{A=}")
print(f"ante:{B=}")

B2.append("xx")
B2.append("ee")

print(f"\npost:{A=}")
```

You could have also use `class myB(list):`, i.e. subclassing rather than decorating.

#### output:

```
ante:A=['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee']
ante:B=['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee']

post:A=['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', 'xx']
```

p.s. not to be too nitpicky, but Python naming conventions strongly discourage capitalized variable names like A, Bcd, those generally signal you're dealing with class variables.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I don't know if this is directly applicable to my case, but it got me thinking in new ways. I also think this answers the question I asked in general, so I will accept the answer!

Answer (score -1):

Don't use `list` where `set` is more appropriate (and much faster in terms of `O(n)`). As a simple example,

```
a_list, b_list = ['aa', 'bb'], ['aa', 'cc']
a_set = set(a_list)
for b in b_list:
    if b in a_set:
        continue
    a_set.add(b)
    a_list.append(b)
```

Check the docs for more details.

P.S. That's a classical trade-off: you sacrifice RAM for performance sake.

Comment: How would you address the ordering requirement that the OP mentions?

Comment: You can have both: set and list trading memory for performance , see no reason for downvote.

Answer (score -1):

Updating a dict with dummy values may be faster and the list (of keys) remains ordered. This works, however, in Python >=3.6. For previous versions you could use `from collections import OrderedDict`.

```
unique_elems = {'aa': None, 'bb': None, 'ee': None}
unique_elems.update({'aa': None, 'cc': None, })
list(unique_elems.keys())

['aa', 'bb', 'ee', 'cc']
```

Comment: 'the list (of keys) remains ordered.' - well, not exactly. For Python3.6+, *insertion* order in maintained. There is no guarantee for <3.6, so perhaps the answer should mention this. Also, doesn't inserting dummy keys kind of mess up that insertion order? I.e. What if one of my dummy keys is supposed to be inserted later down the line? Finally, what if I actually don't want insertion order, but some other ordering?

Comment: I added the Python version comment. An option could be to use OrderedDict for previous versions. You are right that this solution allows to append or prepend, but not inserting. You can also sort the final list. However, I think that appending is what Marcus is asking for.

Comment: @ronkov I think this seems like a creative and somewhat hacky approach. I will keep it in the back of my mind and maybe try it if necessary.

Comment: @Marcus I timed this solution vs `[A.append(b) for b in B if not b in A]`  and it seemed to work like 100 times faster (for 1000 items in A and B), so I would give it a try